# Injection error after updating to RC5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Getting the following error when starting the app:

```
Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for UserView: (AppContext, ClientService, GraphApiService, FiggApiService, AgendaService, AttendeeService, ?, TagService, HelperService, ProgressIndicatorService, TemplateService, MeetingTemplateService, InfiniteLoaderService)
```

Following is my `maint.ts` file which does the bootstrapping of the app:

```
import { enableProdMode, NgModule, ApplicationRef, provide, ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { routing } from './app/app.routing';
import * as pages from './app';
import * as components from './app/shared/components';
import * as directives from './app/shared/directives';
import * as pipes from './app/shared/pipes';
import * as services from './app/shared/services';
import * as models from './app/shared/models';

declare var Office: any;

// depending on the env mode, enable prod mode or add debugging modules
if (process.env.ENV === 'build') {
  enableProdMode();
}

var appContext = new models.AppContext();
var clientService: services.IClientService

//Office based init
if (!(!this.Office)) {
    Office.initialize = (reason: any) => {
        if (!Office.context.document) {
            clientService = new services.OutlookClientService();
            clientService.initializeContext(appContext)
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                    console.log(('Booting using OutlookClientService'));
                    services.Trace.write('Booting using OutlookClientService');
                    boot();
                }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
        }
        else {
            clientService = new services.OfficeClientService();
            clientService.initializeContext(appContext)
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                    console.log('Booting using OfficeClientService');
                    services.Trace.write('Booting using OfficeClientService');
                    boot();
                }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
        }
    };
}
else {
    //Browser based init
    clientService = new services.BrowserClientService();
    clientService.initializeContext(appContext)
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log('Booting using BrowserClientService');
            services.Trace.write('Booting using BrowserClientService');
            boot();
        }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule, 
    RouterModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
      pages.AppComponent,
      pages.UserView
      pipes.OrderBy
  ],
  providers: [
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, helperService: services.HelperService, authProvider: models.AuthProvider) => 
            new services.CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, helperService, authProvider),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, services.HelperService, models.AuthProvider]
    }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }), // can be switched to HashLocationStrategy if you cannot configure your server appropriately for URL rewriting
    provide(ExceptionHandler, { useClass: models.FiggExceptionHandler}),
    provide("GraphApiService", { useClass: services.GraphApiService }),
    provide("AppContext", { useValue: appContext }),
    provide("ClientService", { useValue: clientService }),
    services.AgendaService,
    services.AttendeeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [pages.AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {}

}

export function main() {
  return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}

export function boot(){
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    main();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
  }
}
```

Constructor of the component `UserView` in question:

```
constructor( @Inject("AppContext") private context: AppContext,
    @Inject("ClientService") private clientService: IClientService,
    @Inject("GraphApiService") private graphService: IApiService,
    private figgApiService: FiggApiService,
    private agendaService: AgendaService,
    private attendeeService: AttendeeService,
    private routeParams: Params,
    private tagService: TagService,
    private helperService: HelperService,
    private progressIndicatorService: ProgressIndicatorService,
    private templateService: TemplateService,
    private meetingTemplateService: MeetingTemplateService,
    private loaderService: InfiniteLoaderService){ }
```

My best guess is that the services I have provided in `providers: [...]` is not getting resolved and thus their instances cannot be instantiated when routing to that component. But the question is why though and why is there a `?` mark among the parameters? What does that mean?

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimal reproducible example. This means for example to remove all components from imports and `declarations` that are not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Removed some code for brevity.

Comment: What are the parameters of `UserView`? Please add the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `RouteParams` in RC.5 anymore.

Inject the `ActivatedRoute` instead and get the params like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
   });
}
```

or with

```
this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: To avoid any build errors I changed previously `RouteParams` to `Params`. So, should not that work at least?

Comment: `Params` is not provided anywhere. That's just a class the router uses, but it's not an injectable service. If it's just to get rid of compiler errors, you can try to add it to `providers: [...]` but don't expect it to do anything meaningful this way.

Comment: You were right it helped me get out of that error but now I am getting the same error but from a component that takes in my services and nothing from Angular `constructor(private authProvider: AuthProvider, @Inject("GraphApiService") private graphService: IApiService, @Inject("AppContext") private context: AppContext, private figgApiService: FiggApiService)`

Comment: Its now saying `Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for WordDocumentService: (AuthProvider, GraphApiService, AppContext, ?).`

Comment: This means that something is wrong with `FiggApiService`

Comment: But the whole app is running fine in Beta 8 this is its constructor `FiggApiService`  `constructor(private http: Http, private authProvider: AuthProvider, @Inject("AppContext") private appContext: AppContext)`. Something wrong with my `@NgModule`?

Comment: Is `FiggApiService` listed in `providers: [...]`. The code in your question is now shortened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122285/discussion-between-lbrahim-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Yes it is included under `providers: [...]`. All the services I have are.

Comment: Does the order matter though?

Comment: The order of providers only matters insofar that if one provider is added multiple times, only the last one added is used.